# What does p-value mean in Multiple Regression Analysis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I was trying to learn the usage of p-value in Multiple Regression Analysis. I have found the following sentence which meaning is not clear to me.

**If the null hypothesis is true (b1=0), the chance of us getting a sample AS EXTREME AS we did**.

I found another sentence like above.

**The P value is the probability of seeing a result *AS EXTREME AS* the one you are getting (a t value as large as yours) in a collection of random data in which the variable had no effect.**

I found this sentence in this [link.](https://dss.princeton.edu/online_help/analysis/interpreting_regression.htm#ptse)

The meaning of ***AS EXTREME AS*** for this case is not clear to me at all. Since English is my second language, I cannot understand how the statements stated above explain the importance and usage of p-value.

I would be grateful if anyone would explain the above statements in such a way that a non-native speaker of English can easily understand the actual sense.

Comment: The p-value is the "chance" of obtaining the sample you got if your coefficients where 0. When the p-value is small, it means hardly you would obtain the sample if you have with a coefficient 0, then it must be different of 0.

Comment: @Brunaw: No it's not - see the linked duplicates.